# Passing multiple PHP variables in URL for e-commerce cart?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on an e-commerce project where I've to add product to cart with the selected color, size and quantity. The product gets successfully added into the cart but the color, size and quantity values return null. I tried to use `&_POST` `$_GET` method but still the values aren't returning.

**Add To Cart Front-End**

```
                                    <div class='product-action d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb--10 mt--20'>
                                        <select name='sizes' id='sizes' class='customDrop'>
                                            $listSizes
                                        </select>
                                        <select name='colors' id='colors' class='customDrop' style='width:15rem'>
                                            $listColors
                                        </select>
                                        <div class='quantity'>
                                            <input type='number' class='quantity-input' name='qty' id='qty' value='1' min='1' max='10' readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href='shop.php?add_wishlist=$pro_id'><i class='dl-icon-heart2'></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='product-action d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb--30 mt--20'>
                                        <a href='shop.php?add_cart=$pro_id'>
                                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-style-1 btn-semi-large add-to-cart'>
                                                Add To Cart
                                            </button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

**Cart Function PHP:**

```
function cart(){

    global $conn;

    if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])){

        $ip_address = getIp();
        $size = $_GET['sizes'];
        $color = $_GET['colors'];
        $quantity = $_GET['qty'];
        $product_id = $_GET['add_cart'];

        $check_product = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_address = '$ip_address' AND product_uid = '$product_id'";
        $run_check_product = mysqli_query($conn, $check_product);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check_product) > 0){

            echo "";

        } else {

            $insert_product = "INSERT INTO cart (ip_address, product_uid, product_color, product_size, quantity) VALUES ('$ip_address','$product_id', '$color', '$size', '$quantity')";
            $run_insert_product = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_product);

            echo "<script>window.open('shop.php', '_self')</script>";
        }

    }

}
```

This URL successfully inserts the product `shop.php?add_cart=$pro_id` but the remaining values return blank.

What I want to achieve on `Add To Cart` click is `shop.php?add_cart=$pro_id&size=(selected size)&color=(selected color)&qty=(selected qty)`, how can we do this?

I'm new to PHP and MySQL, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you wrap your inputs and select in a  tag? It seems that you have not.

```
 <div class='product-action d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb--10 mt--20'>
        <form action="/shop.php" method="get"></form>
        <select name='sizes' id='sizes' class='customDrop'>
            $listSizes
        </select>
        <select name='colors' id='colors' class='customDrop' style='width:15rem'>
            $listColors
        </select>
        <div class='quantity'>
            <input type='number' class='quantity-input' name='qty' id='qty' value='1' min='1' max='10' readonly>
        </div>
        <a href='shop.php?add_wishlist=$pro_id'><i class='dl-icon-heart2'></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class='product-action d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb--30 mt--20'>
        <a href='shop.php?add_cart=$pro_id'>
           <button type="submit" value="Submit">Add to Cart</button>
        </a>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Wrap your input and select under a form tag and also change the add to cart button to type submit. If you need your product id you can also create a hidden input to store that to pass to shop.php.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp

Answer (score 0):

You do not submit the chosen values for sizes and colors as long as your submit button is wrapped in an a tag which references to another url than your form action attribute.

Just refactor your form.

```
<form id="product-form" action="./shop.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?= htmlspecialchars( $product_id ) ?>">
    <!-- all your product property inputs here -->
    <button type="submit">add to card</button>
</form>
```

Just use the form tag with the correct attributes. do not wrap any element in an a-tag which won 't submit the values of the form.

Additionally your database query is wide open for sql injection. This is a large security issue. you have to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to stay secure.

Comment: It is not adding the `add_cart=$pro_id` in the URL, instead it's executing just as `/shop.php?sizes=XL&colors=Royal+Blue&qty=3` how can I get to add that after shop.php?

Comment: I 've edited my answer an added an input element of the type hidden. This hidden input element got the name `product_id`. In the given example this will result in `shop.php?product_id={product_id}&sizes={sizes}&colors={colors}&qty={qty}`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! And thanks for letting me know, I'll change those queries into prepared statements, means a lot!